# sql query with exception

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

A table

```
column1         column2         column3         column4
340             9870            abc             mno
338             9870            abc             mno
337             3456            abc             mno
336             3456            abc             mno
335             3456            abc             mno
334             3456            abc             mno
332             3456            abc             mno
331             3456            abc             mno
252             2132            abc             mno
251             2132            abc             mno
249             2132            abc             mno
```

Expected output

```
column1         column2         column3         column4      column5
340             9870            abc             mno           1
338             9870            abc             mno           9
337             3456            abc             mno           8
336             3456            abc             mno           7
335             3456            abc             mno           6
334             3456            abc             mno           5
332             3456            abc             mno           4
331             3456            abc             mno           3
252             2132            abc             mno           2
251             2132            abc             mno           1
249             2132            abc             mno           1
```

Is it possible to generate row number within partition by column3 and column4, order by on column2, column1 when values in column1 are in a sequence, but with an exception : 252 and 331 must be considered sequential as a special case while generating row number.

Code below works without the exception

```
select t1.*,
row_number() over (partition by column3,column4, column1 - num order by column2,column1 ) as column5
from (select t.*,row_number() over (partition by column3,column4 order by column2,column1) as num
from table1 t
     ) t1
order by column2 desc,column1 desc
```

Comment: Do you want column1='252' ,column1='331' counting row_number() separately?

Comment: is `column1`=`332` also an exception?

Comment: my question rephrased: are `332` and `334` must also be considered as sequential? I see that their `column5` values are in sequence.

Comment: Do you have any values between 252 and 331?

Comment: hello.. if you think one of the answers is the best solution to your problem, can you please accept it? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Upvoted your answer @Junjie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a gaps-and-islands problem.  Assuming there are  no values between 252 and 331, then you can use `lag()` to determine where a grouping begins, a cumulative sum, and your final result is a `row_number()` on the grouping.

I also don't see a role for `column2`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by column3, column4, grp order by column1) as column5
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_column1 is null or
                           (prev_column1 <> column1 - 1 and
                            prev_column1 <> 252 and
                            column1 <> 331
                           )
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) over (partition by column3, column4 order by column1) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(column1) over (partition by column3, column4 order by column1) as prev_column1
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cf0a01e15f9a371a0abef3b336125faf) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that your sample data also has a break at 333, which this picks up.  However, this shows how you can address the question that you asked.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using nesting ranking functions, like so:

```
select
  t3.column1, t3.column2, t3.column3, t3.column4,
  row_number() over (partition by column3,column4,seq_num order by column2,column1) column5
from (
  select t2.*,
    sum(seq) over(partition by column3,column4 order by rn) as seq_num
  from (
    select t1.*,
      case when seq=1 then column1 end seq_begin,
      row_number() over (partition by column3, column4 order by column2, column1) rn
    from (
      select t.*,
        case
          when lag(column1) over (partition by column3, column4 order by column2,column1)+1=column1
            or column1 in (331,334) then 0
          else 1
        end seq
      from table1 t
    ) t1
  ) t2
) t3
order by column2 desc, column1 desc
```

Explainig it from the inner subquery then out: I first determined if the row is in sequence or not with the "previous" row using `lag`, and considered in `column1 in (331,334)` the special cases `331` and `334` which "ignores" the previous row. Then I set the `column1` value in `seq_num` for those rows that marked the beginning of a sequence, and added the `rn` as reference within the sequence. Then I created a group number by creating a running total using the `seq` and order by `rn`. The resulting `row_number()` in the outer query produces the desired `column5` by adding the `seq_num` as a partition.